# How to verify a App Store Order ID received from a buyer's Apple receipt email?

Tags: ios, app-store

A user claims that he bought a in-app and sends me a Order ID from Apple receipt email that looks like MKQHK4Y9LF. In our database there are only Transaction IDs collected from reseipt verification prosses that looks like 1000000566193414. How to check whether the in-app were purchased having only the Order ID from the user's Apple receipt email?

Comment: I don't believe that you can correlate the two pieces of information.  They should contact Apple App Store support who can investigate and arrange a refund.

Comment: You do not have access to that kind of information and as @paulw11 said, they'll need to contact Apple Support

Comment: You could map the orderid with transactionid through lookup order id API , please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74371531/3011380

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trust me there are no ways to link the data you have stored in your DB against email data (MKQHK4Y9LF) you received from User.

Using verify purchase you get original txn Id and other details but not the Id sent in Email. Apple considers that a PI.

The only way to get to know that is the userID, with each txn(subscription) you must be(should be) storing user id (emailID).

```
There should be a mapping of userID (email, guid etc) and original_transaction_id
```